# Appearance Settings and PiX theme missing

Tags: gui, update

I upgraded to Jessie using [this guide](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=121880) but the `/usr/share/themes/PiX` directory is missing. I also do not see Appearance Settings in the Preferences menu, which I believe is somewhat linked to the new theme.

From Googling I believe the executable is called `pipanel` but I cannot find this via any of:

- `apt-cache search pipanel`
- `apt-file search pipanel`
- `dpkg -S pipanel`

Where does the utility/theme come from?

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a `pipanel` package, but as per [this post](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/changes-to-the-raspbian-user-interface/) it should be installed as a dependency of `raspberrypi-ui-mods`. Trying to install this showed me that `pipanel` was "not installable" (explaining why I could not find it).

Reading over the upgrade guide again, I realised that I had missed one step: adding `ui` to the end of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list`. I then re-ran:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get distupgrade
```

This does do some work but does not automatically install `raspberrypi-ui-mods`. I can however install it manually (`apt-get install raspberrypi-ui-mods`). It's not clear to me what other packages will now be missing due to the absence of this repo during the upgrade.

Comment: I used `grep ^Package /var/lib/apt/lists/acrhive.raspberrypi.org_debian_dists_jessie_ui_binary-armhf_Packages | awk '{ print $2 }' | xargs dpkg -l` to find out what else was in the repo that was not installed. Only `alacarte`, `dhcpcd5` and some dev/debug packages were not. I installed `alacarte`, but the "correct" DHCP setup on Jessie is still not clear to me.

Comment: The post linked in the answer and a bit of Googling plus the fact that the dhcpcdui tray icon says "`dhcpcd not running`" suggests that the new way is `dhcpcd5`. However, installing it does not remove `isc-dhcp-*` and several Google results have people removing `dhcpcd5` due to conflicts between the two or problems assigning a static IP.